# C++ switch statement odd output

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm working on a final assignment for an Intro to C++ course. What I've coded so far **works**, but it's producing some interesting output that I'm looking for clarification on. Here's my code:

(Caveat: Yes, I know using `void main()` sucks, but we're using Visual Studio in class, and this is the instructors preference.)

```
#include <string> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

void conversion(int);

void main() 
{
    int decimal_number, answer;

    cout << "Please enter a whole decimal number (e.g. 20): ";
    cin >> decimal_number;

    if (decimal_number == 0)
    {
        answer = 0;
        cout << "The hexadecimal value of your number is: " << answer;
        getchar();
        getchar();
    }
    else if (decimal_number < 0)
    {
        cout << "INVALID ENTRY" ;
        getchar();
        getchar();
    }
    else if (decimal_number > 0)
    {
    conversion(decimal_number);
    }

getchar();
getchar();

}

void conversion (int decimal_number)
{
    int count = 0, remainder, reverse_order;
    char hexadecimal_number[10] = { NULL };

    while (decimal_number != 0)
    {
        remainder = decimal_number % 16;

        switch (remainder)
        {
        case 0: 
            hexadecimal_number[count] = '0';
            count++; 
            break;
        case 1: 
            hexadecimal_number[count] = '1';
            count++; 
            break;
        case 2: 
            hexadecimal_number[count] = '2';
            count++; 
            break;
        case 3: 
            hexadecimal_number[count] = '3';
            count++; 
            break;
        case 4: 
            hexadecimal_number[count] = '4';
            count++; 
            break;
        case 5: 
            hexadecimal_number[count] = '5';
            count++; 
            break;
        case 6: 
            hexadecimal_number[count] = '6';
            count++; 
            break;
        case 7: 
            hexadecimal_number[count] = '7';
            count++; 
            break;
        case 8: 
            hexadecimal_number[count] = '8';
            count++; 
            break;
        case 9: 
            hexadecimal_number[count] = '9';
            count++; 
            break;
        case 10: 
            hexadecimal_number[count] = 'A';
            count++; 
            break;
        case 11: 
            hexadecimal_number[count] = 'B';
            count++; 
            break;
        case 12: 
            hexadecimal_number[count] = 'C';
            count++; 
            break;
        case 13: 
            hexadecimal_number[count] = 'D';
            count++; 
            break;
        case 14: 
            hexadecimal_number[count] = 'E';
            count++; 
            break;
        case 15: 
            hexadecimal_number[count] = 'F';
            count++; 
            break;
        default: 
            cout << decimal_number << "+++ " << hexadecimal_number;
            cout << "INVALID ENTRY";
            getchar();
            getchar();
        } 

        decimal_number = decimal_number / 16;

    } 

    cout << "The hexadecimal value of your number is: ";

    for (reverse_order = count -1; reverse_order >= 0; reverse_order--)
    {
        cout << hexadecimal_number[reverse_order];
    } 

    getchar();
    getchar();

}
```

So, like I said: my code works. I can take any number input as a decimal, and convert it to its hexadecimal equivalent. However, I've found that I've had to include an `IF` statement within the main function of the code, because if the user inputs anything **other** than a decimal number into the `decimal_number` variable, the program will store a string of decimal numbers, into `decimal_number`, and I have no idea where those numbers come from. They don't appear to be the ASCII equivalents of anything.

... If none of this makes any sense, I'm sorry. just input `cout << decimal_number` after the line `cin >> decimal_number`, then run the code and see what weird number comes out. I hope that makes things clearer.

Anyway, my instructors stumped, and I'm stumped. I've got the above workaround in place that the instructor will accept, but for my own sanity, I just want to figure out what's going on. Any help or pointers is appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: tell your instructor that standard `C++` mandates `int main()`

Comment: If your instructor is stumped by this, well, that doesn't surprise me, considering what we know about him/her so far.

Comment: If you prefer one line to dozens, that could be written `hex[count++] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[dec%16]`. And fire your instructor; `void main()` is not standard C++, and they really should know how to validate numeric input.

Comment: If you do initialize decimal_number to 0, do you still get wrong input... I think issue is mostly because of uninitialized memory

Comment: _"(Caveat: Yes, I know using void main() sucks, but we're using Visual Studio in class, and this is the instructors preference.)"_ Oh god

Comment: @entre. If I initialise decimal_number to 0, that does work, because any input that is not 0-9 does not seem to get stored. However, I'll have to rewrite some code, because my first IF statement won't work well. It does appear to be related to uninitialised memory. Thanks, folks. I'll have to play around with it some more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test whether the result of `cin >> decimal_number` succeeded, like

```
if(!(cin>>decimal_number))
    throw std::runtime_error("Oops, not a decimal number!");
```

This is a bit too extreme, you can also validate the input:

```
while(!(cin>>decimal_number))
{
    std::cout << "Not decimal, input again ";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

If you're not performing this kind of validation, then you leave the stream in an invalid state whenever reading a non-decimal, and the variable you think you're reading into will end up un-initialized.

Comment: Thanks @vsoftco for the idea about validation. We never discussed it in class, but it's obviously **very** valuable! I'm going to have to read up on this so I understand how it works, but it looks like it's comparing the input value to decimal_number using a logical NOT, and returning an error if that comparison is not a decimal number. Thanks!

Comment: @Dizzzeh almost... the stream defines an `operator bool`, so it can convert itself to a `bool`. This conversion tells you if the read was successful or not.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I've found that I've had to include an IF statement within the main function of the code, because if the user inputs anything other than a decimal number into the decimal_number variable, the program will store a string of decimal numbers, into decimal_number, and I have no idea where those numbers come from.

Well, you did not initialise `decimal_number` to anything, and you do not have any error checking around the `cin >> decimal_number` call. So I'm not sure what else you expected but an unspecified value for `decimal_number`!

Your instructor should know this. It's worrying that, on top of teaching you to write code that is ill-formed per the International Standard (`void main`!!), they failed to discover this problem or note that you have no error checking.

Comment: If this happens at a college/univ. level then it's quite sad. No surprise then we hear lots of programmers rant about C++ being hard and prone to errors. Of course it is if you don't learn to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of the assignment?

The conversion can be simplified to:

```
cout << hex << decimal_value << endl;
```

Or if you need it in a string:

```
std::string convert_decimal_to_hex_string(int decimal_value)
{
  std::ostringstream output;
  output << hex << value;
  return output.str();
}
```

I believe the class should show you how to use `std::string` and existing language features (such as the `hex` manipulator).  Using `char` for a string is dangerous.

Also, since you don't know the size or limit of the decimal values, you will need to dynamically allocate (i.e. during run-time) the array holding the characters.  Think about allocating 2 characters and entering the value 1024; buffer overflow.

Change your program to use `std::string`.  Refrain from character (C-Style) arrays.

Comment: downvote because the OP mentioned that his assignment is already done but he needs clarification on one point that you do not mention and also your proposal contains an error